# Why are primitives types stored in call stack instead of the heap?

Tags: javascript, heap-memory, callstack

My understanding is that call stack is supposed to keep track of which codes are getting executed, and memory heap is where the data is stored. However, I recently discovered that call stack also store data (such as primitive types)? If the purpose of heap is to store data, why are primitives stored in call stack?

Comment: @jabaa Your comment is not particularly instructive. Additionally, I don't see any fault with that understanding. The call stack keeps track of code to be executed and data is indeed stored in the heap.

Comment: Call stack is to keep track of methods currently running. You can create local variables in your method, so that’s the reason it stores it in stack. If you have created variables on the instance then it will be stored in Heap.

Comment: @GenericUser The question doesn't make sense because the premise is wrong. You can write large productive applications without any heap memory. This separation (stack for code execution and heap for data) doesn't exist. There are even fields where heap allocation isn't allowed for security reasons.